# Problema con fetch_all(), no obtiene filas

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando un ejercicio con `fetch_all()`, se supone que tiene que mostrar los datos de la BD en un array pero no muestra nada.

```
<?php

try {
    require_once ('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `registros`; ";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

?>

<?php while($registros= $resultado-> fetch_all() ) { ?>
    <pre>
    <?php var_dump($registros);?>
    </pre>
<?php } ?>
```

Si cambio `fetch_all()` por `fetch_assoc()`, si muestra los datos pero en arrays independientes. Estoy usando `MAMP`.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo completo de tu código por favor. Con ese extracto de código no podemos deducir cuál podria ser el problema

Comment: Pon toda la sentencia desde que inicias la conexion a tu BBDD para poder ayudarte

Comment: @CarlosEstarita asi hago la consulta, me puedo conectar y extraer datos de la BD hasta eliminar y actualizar, pero cuando quiero usar fetch_all() nada mas no puedo.

Answer (score 0):

La proxima vez utiliza las librerias mysqli o PDO para trabajar con tus bases de datos, ya que mysql esta  actualmente no se utiliza mucho, pero cuando estas trabajando en acceder a un campo de la tabla en especifico y meterlo dentro de un div, o algo dinamicamente, yo lo hago con PDO, y te dejo mi forma de hacerlo

```html
              try
               {
        $bbdd_conection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mi_tabla", "root", "");
                  if
                    ($bbdd_conection->errorCode())
                   {
                    die("Fallo al conectar con la base de datos");
                   }else {
     $bbdd_conection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
               $bbdd_conection->exec('SET CHARACTER SET UTF8');
               $stm = "SELECT * nombre_tabla"
               $objeto = $bbdd_conection->prepare($stm);
               $objeto->execute();
               $resultado_demi_tabla = $objeto->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
               foreach($resultado_demi_tabla as $valor){
                   print_r($valor) // usarlo para testear
                   echo $valor->campo1

                   //Con esto podras acceder a cada campo que devuelve el registro de tu tabla, si tu tabla se llama nombre,edad etc con $valor->edad podras ver los resultados y utilizarlos.
               }

               //
                   }
               } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                    echo "Fallo al conectar o enviar una consulta a la base de datos en la linea " . $ex->getLine()
                    . " y el causante del fallo es " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
               }finally{
                   $bbdd_conection = NULL;
               }

            }


        }
```

>

Answer (score 0):

(Suponiendo que estás usando mysqli)
A diferencia del método `fetch`, la salida de `fetch_all` no se recorre, sino que se usa directamente.

```
<?php

try {
    require_once ('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `registros`; ";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
    echo "</pre>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Ojo, los métodos se llaman distinto en `mysqli` que en `PDO`. No nos dijiste cuál estás usando.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución al problema, cambie este codigo:

```
<?php while($registros= $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
   #codigo 
<?php } ?>
```

Por este otro:

```
<?php $registros= array() ?>
      <?php while($registro= $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <?php $registros[] = $registro; ?>
      <?php } ?>
```

De este modo obtuve el mismo resultado. Aclaración: si estoy usando msqli y también use el fecth_all() directamente pero no funciono. Gracias a todos por su ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Se recomienda no usar nunca SELECT *  no ser que vayas a usar todas las columnas de la tabla. Que los SELECT tengan siempre sólo aquello que vas a mostrar o a evaluar. Se notará la diferencia, sobre todo en bd grandes.